# How to run Background service in ios even when app is in suspended state

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, cocos2d-iphone

I don't know how to implement background services.But in searching internet 
I got to see some tutorials regarding Background fetch Api which was introduced in ios 7. I'm unable to understand the process to implement.Plesae provide some help.`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.


    [application setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum];





    return YES;
}
- (void)                application:(UIApplication *)application
  performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{

    NSLog(@"hai");



    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.30
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(sampleTest)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:NO];
     completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}

    -(void)sampleTest
{

    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"hai" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alertView show];


}
```

calling only while the app is launching but after that I could not see any alerts after 30 secs

Comment: You won't see an alert, this is not what the background fetch is for. You cannot manually trigger a background fetch unless you use a silent push notification (iOS 7 only). iOS will call this method when it wants to, you can simulate it in the simulator by going to Xcode > Debug > Simulate background fetch. I doubt the alert will show though as your app isn't in the foreground.

Comment: Xcode > Debug > Simulate background fetch if I do this alert is coming only when simulator is launching but I can't see while it is in active state

Comment: It won't appear when app is active. It's a background fetch ...

Comment: I want some service to run in background while application is in  running or even it is in background state .what to do.

Comment: Well while it's running is easy enough to do. Just call what you want. In background is a bit trickier, your app can only run in the background with Apples pre-determined types i.e. GPS, audio etc .. Alternatively, in iOS7 you can trigger the perormFetchWithCompletion manually using a silent push notification. (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS7.html) - Multi tasking enhancements. But again this is throttled by APNS + iOS to avoid spamming. People don't want apps to do heavy computations after they are closed without knowing...

Comment: You may need to reconsider your requirements/implementation.

Answer (score 0):

just use the following codes :-

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    UIApplication  *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = 0;
    bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    }];
}
```

and

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [application setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum];
}
```